# Comparing characters in java?

Tags: java, string, char, compare, charat

I'm very new to code, and am encountering a problem when I try to create an if/else statement with comparing characters. In the code I'm trying to write, the user is 'gambling' on whether they think a dice roll will be higher than 7, lower than 7, or exactly 7. I've attached the code I wrote for the method that fetches their guess. When I input 'h', 'H', 'l', or 'L' I get the error message, but when I input the 'S' or 's' the method works fine. Any idea why? Thanks in advance!

```
    private static char getHighLow(Scanner inScanner) {
    System.our.print("High, low or sevens (H/L/S): ");
    String str = in.Scanner.nextLine();
    char highLow = str.charAt(0);
    char highOne = 'h'; char highTwo = 'H'; char lowOne = 'l'; char lowTwo = 'L'; char sevenOne = 's'; char sevenTwo = 'S';
    if ((highLow == highOne) | (highLow == highTwo)) {
        highLow = 'h';
    }  
    if ((highLow == lowOne) | (highLow == lowTwo)) {
        highLow = 'l';
    if ((highLow == sevenOne) | (highLow == sevenTwo)) {
        highLow = 's';
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("ERROR- enter h, l, or s");
        System.out.print("High, low, or sevens (H/L/S): ");
        str = in.Scanner.nextLine();
        highLow = str.charAt(0);
    }
    return highLow;
    }
```

Comment: *I get the error message* - please provide this essential information

Comment: You're inputting some user defined string.  Can you give an example of what that input looks like?

Comment: Your `if`s aren't chained. If you want the final `else` to be exclusive to the rest, you need to prefix the others with `else`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think OP is referring to the message printed in the `else`. See my previous comment.

Comment: Is that your actual code? It won't compile for me as it seems to be missing a `}` (and `System.our` is invalid).

Comment: @Ivien `char` compares perfectly fine with `==`, and there is no `Char` (that would be `Character`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `else` block correctly. Better use `else if`:

```
    if ((highLow == highOne) | (highLow == highTwo)) {
        highLow = 'h';
    } else if ((highLow == lowOne) | (highLow == lowTwo)) {
        highLow = 'l';
    } else if ((highLow == sevenOne) | (highLow == sevenTwo)) {
        highLow = 's';
    } else {
        System.out.println("ERROR- enter h, l, or s");
        System.out.print("High, low, or sevens (H/L/S): ");
        str = inScanner.nextLine();
        highLow = str.charAt(0);
    }
```

You can also use switch case for better readability.

Comment: If it helped, please upvote/accept the answer. Thanks!